# Getting an Error when Trying to Update Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code is giving me the error and is not updating the database:

> Uncaught Error: update failed: values argument contains an invalid key ([object HTMLInputElement]) in path /user-Projects/[object HTMLInputElement]/-Mne7bupWgxUwAS-GtVh. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

```
const user = document.getElementById('userName');
//const uid = 0;
const project = document.getElementById('projectName');
const model = document.getElementById('modelName');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
const updateBtn = document.getElementById('updateBtn')

const db = firebase.database();
const rootRef = db.ref('users')
const projRef = db.ref('Projects')

addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //const autoId = rootRef.push().key
    //console.log('Add button clicked')

    //Project Entry
    var projectData = {
        owner: user,
        uid: user,
        title: project    
    };

    //Get a key for a new project
    var newProjectKey = db.ref().child('Projects').push().key;
    console.log(newProjectKey);
    var updates = {};
    updates['/Projects/' + newProjectKey] = projectData;
    updates['/user-Projects/' + user + '/' + newProjectKey] = projectData;

    db.ref().update(updates);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using your `user` variable in the path, which is initialized as

```
const user = document.getElementById('userName');
```

So you're trying to put an HTML element into the path, instead of just the current value from that element, which is what I think you may be trying to do.

To use just the current value of the `userName` element, use:

```
const user = document.getElementById('userName').value;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. I think that the problem is later in the code though. In this section:
    `updates['/Projects/' + newProjectKey] = projectData;`
    `updates['/user-Projects/' + user + '/' + newProjectKey] = projectData;`

Comment: That's indeed where the message comes from, but the problem comes from (as I explained in my answer) not reading the value of the input. Did you try the change I showed in my answer? It's a one-line change, so I recommend trying it.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much for the help!